# Quarantine order dimensions

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In Dynamics AX 2009, when I create a new Quarantine order, all dimensions are copied except the color dimension

it's a dynamics ax bug ?

how can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Try other forums such as the Dynamics AX Community forums for questions regarding the functionality of AX. I'm guessing it is a setup or customization problem, because I'm not able to reproduce the problem in a AX 2009 standard system. Also make sure that your system is on the latest hotfix rollup.